# variável não pega valor do selectedOneMenu

Tags: jsf

Em um form eu tenho o campo onde eu informo o nome e crio uma pasta com esse nome, no segundo form um selectedOneMenu onde lista as pastas que criei no primeiro form, agora meu problema esta no form de upload porque quando eu seleciono uma pasta no selectedOneMenu e clico em fazer upload do arquivo, ele não esta fazendo upload, a variável onde armazeno o nome da pasta esta ficando null, abaixo a minha classe que faz essas operações e o form se alguém puder ajudar fico grato:

```
<div class="f2">
                <label class="fname">

                    <h:form>
                       <center>
                        <label class="fname">

                                Criar Pasta de Upload:&nbsp;&nbsp;<h:inputText value="#{upload_file.pasta}"/>
                                <p:commandButton value="SALVAR" class="btnSalvar" action="#{upload_file.criarDiretorioMacro()}" onclick="#"/>




                            Selecionar Pasta Para Upload:&nbsp;&nbsp; 
                            <h:selectOneMenu id="para" value="#{upload_file.destino}"  style="width: 100px" >

                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="selecione" itemValue=""/>
                                <f:selectItems value="#{dir_controle.selectedDs()}"  />

                            </h:selectOneMenu>
                        </label>
                        </center>
                    </h:form>

                    <h:form class="upload" >
                        <p:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{upload_file.handleFileUpload}" mode="advanced" dragDropSupport="false"
                                      multiple="true" update="messages" sizeLimit="100000" fileLimit="100" allowTypes="/(\.|\/#_)(gif|jpe?g|png|bat|rar)$/"
                                      />

                        <p:growl id="messages" showDetail="true" />
                    </h:form>
                    <br></br>
                </label>
            </div>
```

public class FileUploadView {

```
private String arquivo;
private String pasta;
private String destino;


public String getArquivo() {return arquivo;}

public void setArquivo(String arquivo) {this.arquivo = arquivo;}

public String getPasta() {return pasta;}

public void setPasta(String pasta) {this.pasta = pasta;}

public String getDestino() {return destino;}

public void setDestino(String destino) {this.destino = destino;}

public void criarDiretorioMacro() throws SQLException {
    DirControle dir = new DirControle();
    String directory = dir.selectedDir_CB().toString().replace("[", "").replace("]", "");
    try {
        File diretorio = new File(directory+"//"+getPasta());
        diretorio.mkdir();
    } catch (Exception ex) {

    }
}

public void handleFileUpload(FileUploadEvent event) throws SQLException {
    DirControle dir = new DirControle();
    String directory = dir.selectedDir_CB().toString().replace("[", "").replace("]", "");
    try {

        byte[] arquivo = event.getFile().getContents();

        String caminho = directory +"\\"+getDestino()+ "\\" + event.getFile().getFileName();

        try ( // esse trecho grava o arquivo no diretório
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(caminho)) {
            fos.write(arquivo);

            FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage("Succesful", event.getFile().getFileName() + " is uploaded.");
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, message); // mensagem pra saber se ouve sucesso
        }

    } catch (Exception ex) {

        ex.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println(ex);
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Isso esta errado

```
<f:selectItems value="#{dir_controle.selectedDs()}"  />
```

deve ser algo assim

```
<f:selectItems itemLabel="#{status.name}" var="status" itemValue="#{dir_controle.selectedDs()}" value="#{status}" />
```

Mais ai precisa de converter, se estiver trabalhando com objetos

Comment: Então mas como essa minha linha exibe uma lista o valor dela não deveria ir para o value do selectedOneMenu abaixo?                                      Em outra tela eu realizo esse procedimento e funciona normalmente                                                                                                     <h:selectOneMenu id="para" value="#{upload_file.destino}"  style="width: 100px" >

                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="selecione" itemValue=""/>
                                <f:selectItems value="#{dir_controle.selectedDs()}"  />